# Single razor page with dynamically loaded child pages/partial views/viewcomponents?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm admittedly relatively new to razor pages and I'm trying to understand how best to approach this particular use case.  The application will ultimately be one that has many (potentially +100) different types of forms that users interact with.  These forms will of course be submitted, viewed, approved, worked in queues, etc.

My thinking was that it would be most efficient to have a single page for submitting all these types of forms, a single page for viewing all these types of forms, etc. - so the page would dynamically load the appropriate view based on route parameters.  The partial/viewcomponent/whatever would contain the form element and all the markup/binding/validation/etc. for that form.  I guess where I start going around in circles is, where is the best place for the server-side logic for each form to live?  I would like for each form to be able to support any needed actions themselves.

I first created a razor page for submitting forms.  I thought I'd create ViewComponents with the appropriate markup for each form.  I quickly realized ViewComponents only really support an Invoke method, so that quickly fizzled.  I do believe I could still support multiple actions by leveraging a Controller for each viewcomponent form, but then it seems like I might as well have just gone MVC from the beginning and used partial views for the forms if I'm going to have to have controllers anyway.

Can anyone help me understand whether going the more traditional MVC route here might be more appropriate than trying to make razor pages and viewcomponents do things they may not have been intended for?  Is there any other approach I may be overlooking that might be more appropriate?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than partial views, have you considered razor pages with the model derived from a custom base class, and a common layout page around it?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I have not but would love to hear more about your idea.  Do you have any links/references you could share?  The question that comes to mind is would I be able to stay DRY if I needed a particular version of a form view on more than 1 page?  For example maybe I need to load the Edit version of a particular form view on both a Submit page and an Approvals page?  Maybe I'd flip the script there and let a single Edit page serve both functions conditionally?  Really interesting idea!